# Remove duplicate elements from an array recursively

Tags: java, recursion

I have this code, duplicate elements are removed from the array, it works, but I don't know how to make it recursive

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    dupe cadena= new dupe();
    String arraycar[]={"h","i","e","l","o","i","s","e"};

    System.out.println(arraycar);
    for(int i=0; i<arraycar.length; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<arraycar.length-1; j++){
            if (i!=j){
                if (arraycar[i]==arraycar[j]){
                    arraycar [i]="";
                }
            }
        }
    }
        
    int n= arraycar.length;
    for (int k=0; k<=n-1; k++){
        if (arraycar[k]!=""){
            System.out.println(arraycar[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While your code works, it has a bad string comparison, which can easily stop it from working if you change it slightly, for example, to read the input from user and not hardcode it in your program. Use `arraycar[i].equals(arraycar[j])` instead of `==` operator.

Comment: Aside from bad string comparison, no element of array is removed here, the duplicates are just replaced with an empty string `""`.

Comment: To make something recursive you need a method, which will call itself. So possibly in your case, a method that takes a character and an array as parameters.

Comment: Yet another, and by no means less important note: Please follow Java Naming Conventions and don't name your classes with first lowercase letter. Use `PascalCaseForEachType`.

Answer (score 0):

In current implementation there are nested loops and in the inner loop the duplicate elements are replaced with empty string.

A recursive implementation may replace the outer loop, so the recursive method should have an index argument, and the exit condition will be met when the index achieves the length of the input array.

Example implementation:

```java
public static void removeDuplicates(String[] arr) {
    removeDuplicates(1, arr);
}
    
public static void removeDuplicates(int start, String[] arr) {
    if (start >= arr.length) {
        return;
    }
    String val = arr[start - 1];
    int nonDup = -1; // the index of the first non-empty string to use as start
    for (int i = start; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (val.equals(arr[i])) {
            arr[i] = "";
        } 
        else if (nonDup == -1) {
            nonDup = i;
        }
    }

    if (nonDup >= start) { // non-duplicate candidates are available
        removeDuplicates(nonDup + 1, arr);
    }
}
```

Test

```java
String arraycar[]={"h","h", "i","e","l","o","i","s","e", "s"};

Arrays.stream(arraycar).filter(Predicate.not(""::equals)).forEach(s -> System.out.print(s + " "));
 
removeDuplicates(arraycar);

System.out.println("\nduplicates removed:");
Arrays.stream(arraycar).filter(Predicate.not(""::equals)).forEach(s -> System.out.print(s + " "));
```

Output

```
h h i e l o i s e s 
duplicates removed:
h i e l o s
```

---

However, one of the simplest way would be to use `Stream::distinct` to get rid of duplicates (no recursion needed):

```java
String[] noDups = Arrays.stream(arraycar).distinct().toArray(String[]::new);
```